# A continuous function $f$ is differentiable when so is $|f|$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be any function such that $|f|$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f$ is continuous. Then how to show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

I've started off by writing down the formal definition of differentiability and the definition of continuity, but I'm stuck as to where to go from there.

Comment: You should write down in your question too, so that we can check what you have got.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F=|f|$ Then there exists $L$ s.t. $$ \bigg|\frac{F(x+a)-F(a)}{x-a} - L \bigg| < \epsilon $$

Assume that $f(a) >0$ Then by continuity we have $$\bigg|\frac{f(x+a)-f(a)}{x-a} - L \bigg| < \epsilon $$

If $f(a)<0 $ then $$ \bigg|\frac{-f(x+a)+f(a)}{x-a} - L \bigg| < \epsilon $$

If $f(a)=0$ and $f(a-\delta) <0,\ f(a+\delta ) > 0,\ \delta>0$, then $L=F'(a)=0$ So $$ 
\bigg|\frac{f(x+a) }{x-a} \bigg| < \epsilon $$